# I keep getting "Uncaught SyntaxError:Unexpected token { " in my javascript. I can't figure out why

Tags: javascript

I am programing for this project at my school and in my javascript, I keep getting this error. PLEASE HELP. It will be very much appreciated.

```
var table,row,cell1,cell2,cell3 {
table=document.getElementById("onlineAttendance");
studentInfo= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("studentRecord"));
}
 function myFunction() {
    alert ("Your attendence is submitted");
}
function studentAttendance () {
for (var index=0;index<studentInfo.length;index++) {
    row=table.insertRow(index+1);
    cell1=row.insertCell(0);
    cell2=row.insertCell(1);
    cell3=row.insertCell(2);
    cell4=row.insertCell(3);
    cell1.innerHTML=studentInfo[0].studentNumber;
    cell2.innerHTML=studentInfo[0].firstName+" "+
        studentInfo[0].lastName;  
    cell3.innerHTML=studentInfo[0].absent;
    for (i=0; i<length; i++) 
        if (!document.getElementById(absent).checked)
        {
            studentInfo.points++;
}
```

Comment: you have to close your `if` statement inside the for loop.

Comment: either your problem is obviously your imbalanced { } or you aren't showing all your code....???

Comment: var table,row,cell1,cell2,cell3 {...  also doesn't look like the right way to declare variables, what is that literal at the end doing?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems, first you need a semicolon after your var declarations. You also are doing unnecessary block wrapping (but this is not really a problem, except when trying to debug because indentation should be a concern for everyone).

And finally you are not closing the last `function` and `for` loop (disregarding indentation). But it is possible that you don't need them if you just forgot to copy them with the creation of your question.

```
var table,row,cell1,cell2,cell3;

{
    table=document.getElementById("onlineAttendance");
    studentInfo= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("studentRecord"));
}

 function myFunction() {
    alert ("Your attendence is submitted");
}

function studentAttendance () {
    for (var index=0;index<studentInfo.length;index++) {
        row=table.insertRow(index+1);
        cell1=row.insertCell(0);
        cell2=row.insertCell(1);
        cell3=row.insertCell(2);
        cell4=row.insertCell(3);
        cell1.innerHTML=studentInfo[0].studentNumber;
        cell2.innerHTML=studentInfo[0].firstName+" "+
            studentInfo[0].lastName;  
        cell3.innerHTML=studentInfo[0].absent;
        for (i=0; i<length; i++) 
            if (!document.getElementById(absent).checked)
            {
                studentInfo.points++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```